# Exception Handling in JS using Graal

Tags: java, exception, graalvm

I work on a Java application that makes fairly heavy use of Javascript to form the business logic/glue.  It runs using Graal.  This all works fine, but we struggle with effective error handling.

This is essentially how the JS is executed:

```java
try {
    Context context = Context.newBuilder("js").allowAllAccess(true).build()
    Source s = Source.newBuilder("js", src, "script").build();
    context.eval(s);
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error("Exception occurred in JavaScript:...", e);
}
```

So when errors happen we log them somewhere so we can do some postmortem, etc.  It's possible to get the JS stack trace in these logs out of the `PolyglotException` that Graal throws, which is great.  However, things are more complicated when some JS code has called back into Java-land, and a Java exception has been thrown:

```js
var x = callJavaFunction("invalid parameter"); // Throws a NoSuchElementException, for example
```

The `PolyglotException` has an `asHostException()` method that returns the original Java-land exception, and my code that executes the JS files is smart enough to understand this and produce a useful error log.  **The problem arises when the JS code has tried to catch this itself**, for whatever reason:

```js
try {
    var x = callJavaFunction("invalid parameter"); // NoSuchElementException
} catch (e) {
    doSomeCleanup();
    throw e;
}
```

Now we have **lost the original Exception**, and even worse, the JS-stack trace now just shows us the `catch` block, instead of where the cause was.  `isHostException()` returns `false`, because this is just a JS error now.  I cannot find a way to get at the original cause, which makes diagnosing errors quite difficult, especially when they have come out of a production system.  The original Java exception message ends up in the JS-error object, which is helpful, but we don't have the stack trace, which is not.

**What approaches can I take to try and address this?**

One thought I had:  Can I hook into the GraalVM and get a callback whenever a host-exception is thrown?  At least that way I could have a log saying "the following Java Exceptions were thrown during execution" which I could attach to the error report.  So far I've not been able to find a way to achieve this.

Comment: Maybe it will https://stackoverflow.com/a/58378543/1160581